# pipeline - the object that is being transffered

Tags: design-patterns, .net-4.5, pipeline

I implement a pipeline in c#. Theoretical question - how to shape up the object that is being transferred throughout the chain, considering some in the chain will need to initial source?

```
var InitialSource = SomeSource;
var TransfferedObject = new TransfferedObject();
TransfferedObject.InitialSource = initialSource;
```

Is that would be a best practice (all the examples on the web talk about all handlers take simple string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a simple string is a good choice, because as you know they are **immutable**. And this can
allow immutable classes to use *preconstructed* instances, or to cache
instances as they’re constructed, and dispense them repeatedly to avoid creating
*unnecessary duplicate* objects. If this is your case.

***Update:***

Well it actually **depends by your goals**. If we consider this technique is to be similar to the *Flyweight* pattern. It can greatly improve performance if equivalent objects are requested often, especially if they are expensive to create.

Comment: oh, so passed is string and I should work hard in every handler to "deserailze" the parts it needs? no more OO here? I guess I'll have some performance penalty here...

Comment: mmmm actually every task that is produced in the chain is different. I'd say the question is should I declare "ResultObject" that is transferred between all handlers, or have it input string and output string of all handlers (maybe pay in serialize and deserialize but keep it ready for scale, blocking queue and all??)

Comment: I don't know what your design is, but you can try to create some unit tests for both options and just compare the performance results (as they are important to you).